# Test iAd attribution for iOS app

Tags: ios, iad

Is there a way to test this iAd attribution code snippet? It basically helps me understand my users that came from my iAd campaigns but I don't want to deploy my app without testing that it works first.

https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/iAd-App-Attribution.PDF

Is there any way that I can fake in install that comes from an iAd campaign before pushing my app live?

Comment: I'm unable to find anything that allows testing this code prior to release. A quick Google search returns a few similar questions with no answers. One option may be to use iAd Tester (https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iAd_Tester_Installation_Guide/TestinganAdonaDevice/TestinganAdonaDevice.html) but I don't believe user attribution will be detectable in the test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Having deployed iAd, I was unable to find an attribution method prior to deployment. We double-checked all of our attribution code prior to deployment and hoped for the best. Thankfully, everything was attributed properly and we started seeing attributions within a few days.

I wish there was a better answer out there, but I haven't found one.